# Allow only redirected printer on RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, printing, printer

My Scenario:

- Person A at site A is on the server machine with a local printer at site A.
- Person B at site B is on the Server through RDP and his local printer at site B is listed as redirected on the RDP session.

Problem:

- Every time person B connects using RDP, he has to change his default printer to the redirected one.
- If Person B is using an Application after setting his redirected printer as default printer, the printing is ok. But, in case the RDP session disconnects and reconnects(within 30 Secs), the printer gets changed to the default printer at site A. So when person B issues print, the printing happens at site A rather than site B.

Actual Question:

How to restrict access to printer at Site A for remote user operating from Site B? Is there any Group policy Setting for this? How to make Rdp session retain redirected printers in case of disconnecting/reconnecting issues?

Answer (score 0):

Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc) and navigate to the key
*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Printer Redirection*.

The policy to verify is named
"Do not set default client printer to be default printer in a session",
described as:

> If you enable this policy setting, the default printer is the printer
> specified on the remote computer.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, the RD Session Host server
> automatically maps the client default printer and sets it as the
> default printer upon connection.
>
> If you do not configure this policy setting, the default printer is
> not specified at the Group Policy level.

You should set this to Enabled on the server machine A.

Comment: i believe this policy should be disabled, and yes i had already set this policy to disabled. Didn't help

Comment: Try to set it to Enabled.

Comment: tried it. Didn't help. i need a way to diable all printers except redirected ones for remote users.

Comment: Strange, according to the documentation this should have solved your problem. Perhaps it stopped working in the latest versions of Windows.